# Discarding Right to left not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, right-to-left

My app supports right to left direction but i want to discard the phone language and just change direction depending on the user preference.

On a right to left phone, I forced the left to right using

```
 UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

it fixed most things but not everything.

Check the text fields placeholder alignment; some labels were aligned right! 
Anyone has a solution how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to type from left to right in textfield ?

Comment: @JonSnow yes i am

Comment: Try this TxtField.textAlignment=UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft

Comment: I need a a solution for all textfields one shot

Comment: is that code working for you ?

Comment: ofcourse not .. u can't assign a uitextwriting direction in nstextalignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this one it will change direction of your textfield's text from left to right

```
 extension UITextField {
  open override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    if UserDefaults.languageCode == "ar" {
        if textAlignment == .natural {
            self.textAlignment = .right
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i have tried it myself and its working fine for placeholders as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it will work for all the UITextField or not but You can try this but with single UITextField it should work

```
    UITextField.appearance().makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight(nil)
```